# What is this fourier identity from? $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(y)\hat{g}(y)dy$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575455/evaluate-i-int-limits-infty-infty-frac-sinx-3x-3e-x-dx), Bonrey uses the identity $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(y)\hat{g}(y)dy$$ to attempt to integrate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x-3)}{x-3}e^{-|x|}dx$$
where he defines the fourier transform of a function to be $$\mathcal{F}\left[f(x)\right](y)=\hat{f}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ixy}dx$$

Where is this identity from? The closest formula I could find through intensive searching was Parseval's theorem, which states that for two square integrable functions $f$ and $g$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(y)\overline{\hat{g}(y)}dy$$
where $\overline{f(x)}$ is $f$'s complex conjugate. Due to this conjugation, I do not believe this is the same theorem that Bonrey applied.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Notice that 3 of the 4 functions and transforms involved are all real, so this really is Parseval's theorem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi where does the 1/2pi constant come from tho

Comment: different Fourier transform conventions. Always pay attention to those.

Comment: Ah right, the normalization constant. fair enough :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just like to note a few things in regards to this. In my case with $g(x)=e^{-|x|}$, this is a real, even function.

We know a few things

1. The Fourier transform of an even integrable function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is even real-valued function.
2. For some $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, $f^*(x)=f(-x)$. ($f^*$ is the conjugate of $f$)

If $f(x)$ and its fourier transform are real (which is the case here), then we can say that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)\hat{g}(-s)ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)f(-y)dy$$

If in addition to this, our function is real valued *and* even (which is also the case here), then we can reduce this to the identity in question
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)\hat{g}(s)ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)f(y)dy$$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in questioning the result because it's just not true in general.
$$
   \int_{-R}^{R}\hat{f}(s)\hat{g}(s)ds
  = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-isx}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)e^{-isy}dy ds \\
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(y)\left[\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-is(x+y)}ds\right]dxdy \\
  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(y)\frac{e^{-iR(x+y)}-e^{iR(x+y)}}{-2\pi i(x+y)}dxdy \\
  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(y)\frac{\sin(R(x+y))}{\pi(x+y)}dxdy \\
  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\frac{\sin(R(x+y))}{\pi(x+y)}dxdy
$$
As $R\rightarrow\infty$, the inner integral on the far right plucks out the value of $f$ at $-y$. That's the standard Dirichlet kernel result. Therefore,
$$
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)\hat{g}(s)ds=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(y)f(-y)dy.
$$
If either $g$ or $f$ happens to be even, then you get what you want, but not otherwise, at least not in general.

Comment: Hmm.. could we also argue that, given both $g(x)$ and $\hat{g}(y)$ are purely real, their complex conjugates are themselves, which means that $g(x) = \overline{g(x)}$ and $\hat{g}(y)=\overline{\hat{g}(y)}$, reducing persevals theorem to what we have ($\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)dx = \frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(y)\hat{g}(y)dy$) as suggested by Ninad? Or does this not work given my assumptions?

Comment: Also, I do note that the initial person who posted the integral defined the fourier transform as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ixy}dx$, which is different from your definition. Would this affect the negative of the function parameter at all?

Comment: @Max0815 : If they define the Fourier transform without the correct normalization, then they're also off by a normalization constant, which you can always put on the second integral in the equation if you wish. Regardless, it won't affect the negative in the argument. There must be such a thing, unless--as I mentioned--the function is even. The formula that I gave is correct. There is no sleight of hand there; you can see all the steps used to derive it. That's why I gave you all the steps.